# posting object from angular 2 application to Web Api application (getting Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: api, http, angular, observable

I could use some guidens, sending an object from my angular 2 application to the Web API.

I know how to GET objects from the Web Api, to my angular 2 application, but can't seem to figure out how the post method works or even if I should use the http.post methodd.

**My angular 2 application has the following method:**

```
sendUpdatdReservation(updatedReservation: Reservation) {

    var result;
    var objectToSend = JSON.stringify(updatedReservation);

    this.http.post('http://localhost:52262/api/postbookings', objectToSend)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => result = res);

    console.log(result);

}
```

The "updatedReservation" is an object, which I convert to JSON.

The Web api can be reached by the following address:

httl://localhost:52262/api/postbookings

**Web Api controller:**

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PostBookingsController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs()]
    public bool ConfirmBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to send the object, update my database based on the changes values that the object has. Then send back true or false if this is a confirmation or not so I can redirect to confirmation page.

Do any know the unsupported media type error?, is that related to that the object i send is not what the api method expects?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported Media Type error when posting to Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526558/unsupported-media-type-error-when-posting-to-web-api)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header when sending the request:

```
sendUpdatdReservation(updatedReservation: Reservation) {
  var result;
  var objectToSend = JSON.stringify(updatedReservation);

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post('http://localhost:52262/api/postbookings', objectToSend, { headers: headers })
     .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
       this.result = res;
       console.log(this.result);
     });
}
```

Don't forget to import this class:

```
import {Http,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. now i'm getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, which I should not, cause I have cors enabled.

NVm.. its working now :)